# Is Character equals char autoboxed or unboxed in java?

Tags: java

I'm thinking about this easy code:

```
Character s = 'n';
System.out.println(s == 'y');
System.out.println(s.equals('y'));

s = 'y';
System.out.println(s == 'y');
System.out.println(s.equals('y'));
```

with result

```
false
false
true
true
```

So the result is good but, how does this comparing work? Is Character object unboxed to char or chat is autoboxed to Character?

Comment: This is simply a question of **How autoboxing works** and **how `Character.equals(Object)` are implemented**

Comment: ez +80 reputation.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of the `==` test, the [Java Language Specification, Section 15.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21), explains that the `Character` is unboxed to a `char` (a numeric type).

> The equality operators may be used to compare two operands that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, or two operands of type boolean or Boolean, or two operands that are each of either reference type or the null type.

And in §15.21.1:

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

In the case of `equals()`, the `char` value is boxed to a `Character`, since the argument to `equals()` needs to be a reference type.

Answer (score 5):

The `equals` method you are calling (in `s.equals('y')`) is a method of the `Character` class that takes an `Object` argument. Therefore the `char` argument you are passing to it must be boxed.

There is no need for unboxing, since the `value` member of the `Character` class (whose type is a `char`) is used for the actual comparison :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Character) {
        return value == ((Character)obj).charValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
s == 'y'
```

> Character 's' will unbox itself to `char`.

and when you do this:

```
s.equals('y')
```

> `'y'` will be autobox because equals() is method of the `Character` like @Eran said.

Answer (score 1):

s == 'y' is unboxed, and s.equals('y') is auto boxed. To check it just try to put a break point inside equals method of the Character class and debug your program, you can find out it is auto boxed or unboxed. First case you will not see control getting in, but it is in the second case.